# How to re order rows in matrix base on their values?

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

My matrix contains binary arrays. How to re-order them based on their values?

```
input = [[0,1,0]
[0,0,0]
[1,1,1]]

result = [[0,0,0]
[0,1,0]
[1,1,1]]
```

Comment: sorted(input) ?

Comment: @PremAnand It works. +1 for speed

Comment: @PremAnand it works, amazing answer. I have to learn Python better )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sorted(input)
```

Based on @PremAnand answer.